# Docker build creating dummy ethernet interface

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

Is it possible to create dummy Ethernet interface using Docker build below is snippet from DockerFile build logs.

```
Step 14/17 : run sudo ip link add dummy0 type dummy && sudo ip addr add 192.168.10.12/24 dev dummy0 && sudo ip link set dummy0 up
 ---> Running in 21c388505e28
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

I was able create dummy interface by running the image in privilege mode.